# Should programming/coding questions about OR be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions that are about *programming/coding* aspects of OR be on topic? For example, questions about solvers, modeling languages, coding one's own heuristic, etc.?

I'll post my own opinion below but I hope others will add their own opinions in comments or separate answers.

Answer (score 15):

I think that programming-related questions should be **on topic,** provided that they require some amount of OR-related expertise. I'm taking a cue from [CrossValidated's attitude toward programming questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which says:

> if it needs *statistical expertise* to understand or answer, ask it here

and otherwise ask on StackOverflow or somewhere else (emphasis in original). I like this approach and think we should do something similar.

Obviously, it is impossible to draw a clear line between what's in scope here vs. on SO, nor should we try -- some questions will be in scope on both sites, and it's up to the asker to decide which site to use.

Here are some recent questions from SO that I think **would be in scope** on OR.SE:

- [How to fix constraints for allocation optimisation in PuLP python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365711/how-to-fix-constraints-for-allocation-optimisation-in-pulp-python)
- [Infeasible Solution, Definitely Feasible - CPLEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362389/infeasible-solution-definitely-feasible-cplex)
- [How to write average constraints in CPLEX OPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300705/how-to-write-average-constraints-in-cplex-opl)
- [Solving the assignment problem with specific constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282517/solving-the-assignment-problem-with-specific-constraints)
- [3-opt optimization code for TSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282958/3-opt-optimization-code-for-tsp/28287109#28287109)

Here are some that I think **would not be in scope** on OR.SE:

- [actualSolve raise PulpSolverError(“CPLEX_PY: Not Available”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383377/actualsolve-raise-pulpsolvererrorcplex-py-not-available)
- [pyomo + reticulate error 6 the handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379818/pyomo-reticulate-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid)
- [The order (sequence) of set members imported into GAMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368562/the-order-sequence-of-set-members-imported-into-gams)
- [Connecting to the CPLEX remote API with julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292912/connecting-to-the-cplex-remote-api-with-julia)
- [EA: Custom crossover for a list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279630/ea-custom-crossover-for-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Here are some that I think could go **either way**:

- [Summary of knapsack solve in CPLEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383329/summary-of-knapsack-solve-in-cplex)
- [pyomo creating constraints via a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331132/pyomo-creating-constraints-via-a-loop)

Comment: I agree with your point of view which I signalled with my upvote. Is there an option to add a poll or another way such that others can also vote for "programming questions should be off topic"?

Comment: Yes, just add another answer; folks can vote up or down for whatever answers they like.