# Should program/solver/package specific questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we allow questions regarding concrete solvers (e.g. gurobi, cplex etc.) and other packages? See for example question ["When does Gurobi add cuts from callback"](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/18/when-does-gurobi-add-cuts-from-callback).

Note that commercial packages often have their own support forum. On the other hand (especially for open source frameworks) I'd find it beneficial to have a place where one can ask questions.

What is your opinion?

Comment: related: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-programming-coding-questions-about-or-be-on-topic

Answer (score 12):

I would say questions asking about using a specific software are on-topic if it requires OR knowledge to answer (related: [Should programming/coding questions about OR be on topic?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-programming-coding-questions-about-or-be-on-topic)).

Personally I think questions about implementation details which are not publicly documented should be considered off-topic, as they are not necessarily answerable, and might be highly version-specific.

on-topic:

> How do I add a lazy cut using Gurobi's Java API?

off-topic:

> What is Gurobi's internal representation of the Simplex basis matrix?

Answer (score 3):

> Should program/solver/package specific questions be allowed?

If the answer can't be found by doing a simple search that returns the answer multiple times on the first result page ***and*** the answer will be useful to future visitors then 'How do I do X by using Y, or should I use Z?' type questions should be allowed.

Always be certain to disclose any affiliation with software asked about or included in an answer to avoid some of the problems experienced on our other sites:

- [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange vs. commercial products](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133522/282094) (answered by [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky))
- [Is my enforcement of Stack Overflow's policy against recommendation questions proper?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268287/3648282)
- [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/3648282)
- [Providing support via Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303712/3648282)
- [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/3648282) (asked and answered by [Robert Cartaino](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11/robert-cartaino))

Comment: "_disclose any affiliation with software_"    (+1)