# Reversing decisions during the OR Beta phase?

Tags: discussion, support

The impression I have is that the dividing line between what is on-topic and what is off-topic for OR is still being discerned by the community during this beta.

What happens if a question has been put-on-hold due to concerns about being off-topic, but then subsequent discussion indicates that the question might actually be on-topic after all. What is the appropriate way to have the put-on-hold decision reversed, or at least for this to be considered?

The particular example I am thinking of is

[Installing COIN-OR solvers in Ubuntu (Azure)](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/447/installing-coin-or-solvers-in-ubuntu-azure)

As a working OR professional myself, this kind of question is very much of interest to me and I would be sad to see it permanently judged off-topic. I feel that such a question would be less likely to be well answered in other forums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now?  Vote to re-open it.  There should be a "reopen" link at the bottom of the post, between the "edit" and "flag" links.  This will put the question into the re-open review queue for people to vote on.

Once the site goes into public beta, only people with sufficient reputation (500 or more) will be able to vote for re-opening.  For anyone else, the options are:

- Edit the question to address whatever issues caused it to be closed.  This will automatically place it in the re-open review queue.
- Ask a question on meta about the post, bringing it to the attention of a wider audience (including those people with sufficient reputation to vote for re-opening).
- Flag the post for moderator intervention, explaining why it should be re-opened.  Not the recommended method, since moderators can only re-open or decline to re-open, they can't put it in the review queue.

Answer (score 7):

The main answer, as @Mark said, is *vote to reopen*.

But I'll also add: Nothing is permanent, and even if we (the OR.SE community) decide now that certain questions are off-topic, we can always change our minds at any point in the future.

The thinking in [this post](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12/38) was that questions about installation, etc., that don't require any OR knowledge would be off-topic, even for OR software. However, your point is well taken, and I think I am starting to change my own mind about this question, as well. I might edit that post, or post a new question on meta. Thanks for raising this issue.